Geometry Nodes: How to delete the nearest face?
I am dealing with the following problem: I want to check, which faces of the grid are nearest to Suzanne and delete those faces.
I have tried sample nearest surface etc. but can't quite figure it out.


Define "nearest". Do you want to delete faces that overlap Suzanne? Do you mean overlapping Suzanne's shell (faces), or volume? In the latter case it's a little bit tricky because Suzanne isn't manifold.

1: Method to get a complete hole
If you would want a complete hole inside the grid where Suzanne is, you can first start off with this setup from Robin Betts' answer to this question: find out if vertices are inside or outside of another mesh, using geometry nodes, where he uses the Raycast node to check all vertices in all directions and to find out if they are inside Suzanne or outside. In the other question he uses it for coloring the mesh differently. Using the result of the Vector Math > Dot Product and compared if it is Greater Than 0 however can also be used as Selection in a Delete Geometry node. Theoretically this deletes all vertices which are inside Suzanne and therefore faces which are built from these vertices:

But maybe you noticed that there is a problem - actually two, I'll deal with them one by one. First of all, there is a face (or two) poking inside Suzanne below one eye. This is because unfortunately Suzanne is a non-manifold mesh, there are holes in the eye sockets and the eyes are separate and continue inside the head. Now with the current grid and the head's current position there is this one vertex which is closer to one of the inside faces than the outer surface of the head - so it is calculated as outside (of the eye). With a manifold mesh this would not happen.

So to let this not happen you could make sure you only use target meshes that are manifold. In your specific case though where you have no complex mesh but a simple grid in the XY plane and the eye is slightly above the plane, there is an easy workaround: instead of checking in all directions, you could disable the Z axis by setting the Z value in the Combine XYZ node to 0, this way the slightly higher eye is not taken into account:

Be aware: As soon as the eye cuts through the plane and parts of the inner eye are at Z = 0, this workaround will break (if a grid vertex is closer to the eye than the outer surface). Better would be a manifold mesh. Or another solution might be plugging the target object into a Convex Hull node, but this can also result in a slightly larger hole around the object and you lose some of the contouring detail:

Let's go with the modified version which ignores the Z axis. As I said, you might have noticed two problems. Here is the second one: there is a single edge left, because it has a vertex that is outside the head, but two neighboring vertices to the left and right (or front and back of the head) are inside and deleted, so the faces are gone but the edge between them is still there:

For edges like these I add another Delete Geometry node into the tree. This time, for the Selection I take a Compare node to check if the Face Count from an Edge Neighbors node is either Equal to 0 or Less Than 1, whatever you like, as longs as it sorts out edges that have no faces:

2: Method to get a contour hole
This is a little bit simpler: take a Geometry Proximity and use a Less Than node to check if the Distance is below a certain threshold value. I have set the Geometry Proximity to Faces, of course you could use Edges or Points as well, it all depends what threshold value you use and the result you want to get, some settings might not delete all faces to get a continuous hole around. It also depends on the resolution of your grid of course. In some cases there might be single edges left like with the other method, so I added this Face Count check here as well:


If you want to make a "hole" so the suzanne can fit in it you could duplicate the suzanne and add a boolean modifier to the plain(with the duplicated suzanne being the selected object). If you want to delete the faces, I would go to face select mode, select the faces around the suzanne manually, delete them, and then just select the faces where the suzanne was and delete them.

The second half of that answer sounds like we’re just deleting the whole grid with extra steps. Did you mean invert the selection?

@TheLabCat I guess he means first he's deleting the faces bordering Suzanne, which leaves you with the faces outside of Suzanne and the ones inside Suzanne, and he is deelting the latter ones afterwards. But anyway, for a question that explicitly asks for a Geometry Nodes solution (which is surely possible, I just have to figure out how) I think this answer misses the point.

yes, that's exactly what I meant. sorry for the confusion. I don't think that might be the easiest solution but that's the only way I know.
